# Pagination on demand AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

My doubt is: How to make a demand paging with angularJS ? I have 2 features:

1 - Can not be used jQuery , just Angular or pure Javascript .

2 - I have 2 methods and the prevPage NextPage
Example of the methods below :

```
$ Scope.prevPage = function ( page) {
if ( $ scope.currentPage - 1 > 0 ) {
$ Scope.changePage ( page) ;
}
}

$ Scope.nextPage = function ( page) {
if ( $ scope.currentPage +1 < = $ scope.numberOfPages ) {
$ Scope.changePage ( page) ;
}
}
```

Here to stay is the most visible html :

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li glyphicon-chevron-left" class="glyphicon ng-click="prevPage(currentPage-1)" ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 1}"> < / li >
<li ng-repeat="i in numberOfPagesArr track by $index" ng-class="{active: $index+1 currentPage}" == { { $ index ng-click="changePage($index+1)"> +1 } } < / li >
<li glyphicon-chevron-right" class="glyphicon ng-click="nextPage(currentPage+1)" ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == numberOfPages}"> < / li >
</ul>
```

Is currently running , However on the page loads only 10 pages in pagination
almentar but the number will surely break .

Here 's an example of paging Within a matter of how I want to do :
http://begriffs.github.io/angular-paginate-anything/

If anyone has a suggestion I am grateful .